# importing Python Bokeh Scatter plots not working. Cannot import Default_Palette

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to import Scatter from `bkcharts` and it fails with the following error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-23fcc4dbc1e0> in <module>()
----> 1 from bkcharts import Scatter, output_file, show
      2 import pandas
      3 
      4 df=pandas.DataFrame(columns=["X","Y"])
      5 df["X"]=[1,2,3,4,5]

c:\users\ellamm\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bkcharts\__init__.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 # defaults and constants
----> 5 from bokeh.plotting.helpers import DEFAULT_PALETTE; DEFAULT_PALETTE
      6 
      7 # main components

ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_PALETTE'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am one of the maintainers of Bokeh. You should know (as stated prominently on the project GitHub page) that `bkcharts` is no longer part of core Bokeh, and more importantly, that it is **completely unmaintained** at this point. There is no future work, fixes, or effort planned to put into it, unless someone new decides to take ownership of it. If you must use `bkcharts`, my only suggestion is to not update Bokeh past `0.12.6`, which is the last version that received any testing together.

However, my real advice is simply not to use `bkcharts` at all, for any reason, at this point. It's hard to know exactly what you are after with such a short code snippet, but I will say that all sorts of scatter plots are easy with core `bokeh.plotting`, and if you are after an even higher level interface then [`Holoviews`](http://holoviews.org/) is an officially endorsed  higher level API built on top of Bokeh, that has an active development team working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The following link might help:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#getting-started

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-with-bokeh-in-python-part-one-getting-started-a11655a467d4

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code instead:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,show

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[5,6,4,5,3]

p=figure(title='Simple Example',x_axis_label='X Axis',y_axis_label='Y Axis')
p.circle(x,y)

output_file("Scatter_chart.html")

show(p)
```